# Differential Equations µ substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My professor has removed the lecture notes which were our only resource (no textbook) for the class, so I do not have much to go on except for a class I took years ago. He never named it in class, but I remember calling the solution technique µ sub. I can't find any tutorials that I recognize as being this kind of problem or using the equation he provides.

Solve:
$v'=5-0.1v$

with $v(0)=44$

The hint provided is to use the equation:

$y(x)=e^{-µ(x)}\int{e^{-µ(x)}q(x)dx}$

Comment: A) how could separation of variables work here? B) where does his hint come in? C)if his hint is not used here what form is it used on?

Comment: I'm sorry what? Alternative problem does match this form but never uses that. They simply give an equation for µ but if i use that I end up with e^e^.1t. I actually get lost at after they multiply both sides by their integrating factor. particularly what happens on the left side

Comment: @Moo Are there any better online resources for understanding this? That website skips a critical step and does not solve it using the method my prof intends (which is the only way that I've been taught)

Comment: @Charles Separation of variables applied here would be \begin{align} \frac{dv}{dx} &= 5 - 0.1v \\ \implies \int \frac{dv}{5 - 0.1v} &= \int dx \\ \implies \frac{-1}{0.1} \int \frac{-0.1 dv}{5 - 0.1v} &= \int dx \end{align} and the LHS integrates to a log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$v'=5-0.1v$$
For a DE of this kind ( first order linear DE), the integrating factor $\mu (x) $ is given by:
$$v'+p(x)v=q(x) \implies \mu (x) = \exp \int(p(x))dx$$
Here is a step by step solution:
$$v'+0.1v=5$$
Multiply by integrating factor $\mu (x)= \exp \int(0.1)dx=e^{0.1x}$
$$v'(e^{0.1x})+v(0.1e^{0.1x})=5e^{0.1x}$$
Note that:
$$f'g+fg'=(fg)'$$
$$\implies v'(e^{0.1x})+v(0.1e^{0.1x})=(ve^{0.1x})'$$
So that we have:
$$(ve^{0.1x})'=5e^{0.1x}$$
Now integrate both side
$$ve^{0.1x}=5\int e^{0.1x}dx$$
$$ve^{0.1x}=5\frac 1 {0.1} e^{0.1x}+C$$
$$ve^{0.1x}=50 e^{0.1x}+C$$
Finally multiply both sides by $e^{-0.1x}$:
$$v(x)=e^{-0.1x}50 e^{0.1x}+Ce^{-0.1x}$$
$$ \implies v(x)=50+Ce^{-0.1x}$$

---

For the formula you are given it's the same as what we did:
$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$
Multiply both side by $IF (x) =\exp \int p(x) dx$

Your teacher seems to have taken:

$$\mu = \int p(x)dx \implies IF(x)=e^{\mu (x)}$$

$$y'e^{\mu (x)}+y(x)p(x)e^{\mu (x)}=q(x)e^{\mu (x)}$$
Remember that
$$f'g+fg'=(fg)'$$
$$(ye^{\mu (x)})'=q(x)e^{\mu (x)}$$
Integrate both side:
$$ye^{\mu (x)}= \int q(x)e^{\mu (x)}dx$$
Multiply  both side by $e^{-\mu (x)}$
$$y(x)=e^{-\mu (x)} \left ( \int q(x) e^{\mu (x)}dx \right )$$

---

$$y'+p(x)y=q(x)$$
$$v'+0.1v=5$$
Now apply the given formula but note that $p(x)=0.1$ and $q(x)=5$. Evaluate $\mu (x) = \int p(x)=\int 0.1dx=0.1x$

$$
\begin{align}
y(x)=&e^{-\mu (x)} \left ( \int q(x) e^{\mu (x)}dx \right ) \\
y(x)=&e^{-0.1x} \left ( \int 5 e^{0.1x}dx \right ) \\
y(x)=&e^{-0.1x} \left ( \frac 5 {0.1} e^{0.1x}+C \right ) \\
y(x)=&50+Ce^{-0.1x} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! I could not see that that was the product rule. Again though I am at a complete loss as to how this relates to the equation that my prof provided

Comment: @Charles yw.   Better not to memorize formula like the one you are given. It's better to understand how integrating factor 's method works. The formula you are given is exactly what we did step by step. Except that formula is for any equation of the form $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$

Comment: @Charles I added some lines I hope it explain your teacher 's formula. As you can see there is a sign mistake inside the integral its not a minus side inside.

Comment: With those extra lines it makes a lot of sense, I can see how they're connected now. Thank you!

Comment: Yw @Charles...........And I am happy it hleped you.